# How do I configure a Foundry job to not retry more often than a certain threshold?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a Transform job that runs a particular operation I'd like to prevent from occurring more often than some configurable time threshold, that is, it shouldn't run the operation more than once every X minutes.

My code looks like this:

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform


@transform(
  my_output=Output("/my/output/dataset"),
  my_input=Input("/my/input/dataset")
)
def my_compute_function(my_input, my_output):
  input_df = my_input.dataframe()

  # Do some rate-limited processing...
  my_call()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use two things here:

1. An incremental "last updated" output
2. Abort transaction

We'll store the state of when we last ran inside a second dataset output, and if we detect the timestamp we stored there is less than a certain threshold away, we will abort our run.

This code will look like the following:

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform, incremental
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

MIN_TIME_ELAPSED = timedelta(minutes=30)

RUN_RECORD_SCHEMA = StructType([ \
  StructField("last_run", T.TimestampType(), False),
])


def maybe_get_run_rows(run_record):
  last_run_df = run_record.dataframe("previous", schema=RUN_RECORD_SCHEMA)
  last_run_rows = last_run_df.collect()
  return last_run_rows


def within_run_window(run_record_rows):
  current_run_time = datetime.now()
  last_run_time = run_record_rows[0][0]
  return (current_run_time - last_run_time) > MIN_TIME_ELAPSED:
  

def record_run(run_record, ctx):
  # Record that we ran
  new_run_record_df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(
    [[current_run_time]],
    schema=RUN_RECORD_SCHEMA
  )
  run_record.set_mode("replace")
  run_record.write_dataframe(new_run_record_df)



@incremental(semantic_version=1)
@transform(
  my_output=Output("/my/output/dataset"),
  run_record=Output("/my/output/run_record"),
  my_input=Input("/my/input/dataset")
)
def my_compute_function(my_input, run_record, my_output, ctx):
  input_df = my_input.dataframe()

  run_record_rows = maybe_get_run_rows(run_record)

  if len(run_record_rows) == 0:
    # First run ever

    # Do some rate-limited processing...
    my_call()
    record_run(run_record, ctx)

  else:
    # Not first run ever

    if not within_run_window(run_record_rows):
      # Built too quickly, do nothing

      my_output.abort()
      return

    else:
      # Proceed as normal

      my_call()
      record_run(run_record, ctx)
```

You can now configure the `MIN_TIME_ELAPSED` argument by passing the minimum time elapsed amount you'd like, per the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) docs

If for some reason you wanted to only run one time *ever*, then you could slightly modify your compute function to instead be:

```py
@incremental(semantic_version=1)
@transform(
  my_output=Output("/my/output/dataset"),
  run_record=Output("/my/output/run_record"),
  my_input=Input("/my/input/dataset")
)
def my_compute_function(my_input, run_record, my_output, ctx):
  input_df = my_input.dataframe()

  run_record_rows = maybe_get_run_rows(run_record)

  if len(run_record_rows) == 0:
    # First run ever

    # Do some rate-limited processing...
    my_call()
    record_run(run_record, ctx)

  else:
    # Not first run ever

    my_output.abort()
    return
```